Firebase email authentication not sending email verify
React Native Project
I have a function that handles user registration based on Firebase Authentication.
Currently it is not sending authentication email to the user, I have tried many ways.
I'm new to Firebase authentication, hoping someone can help me.
Package.json
{
  "name": "ChattingApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "firebase": "^10.10.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.8.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}



Fix firebase authentication email sending in React Native project

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
